# Loop for dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have the following script:

```
from collections import defaultdict

class OrderLine:
   def __init__(self, shop_id, qty, price):
    self.shop_id = shop_id
    self.qty = qty
    self.price = price

order_lines = [OrderLine(1, 2, 30), OrderLine(1, 1, 50), OrderLine(3, 3, 10)]
shop_sum = defaultdict(int)
for order_line in order_lines:
   print order_line.price
   print order_line.qty
   print order_line.shop_id
```

each line consists of (shop_id, qty, price) I want to loop for this shop_sum  to give me for each shop_id:

```
total_price = qty * price
```

example: I have shop ids (1,3) , in shop_id =1
I have two order lines [OrderLine(1, 2, 30), OrderLine(1, 1, 50)]
I want to calculate the total price for all order lines which has the same shop_id where: total_price = qty * price

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify. Are you saying you want a dictionary whose keys are ids and whose values are total prices? Or something else? Please give a concrete example of the exact output you want to get.

Comment: I have shop ids (1,3) , in shop_id =1 I have two order lines, I want to calculate the total price for all order lines which has the same shop_id where:
total_price = qty * price

Answer (score 1):

You can populate your dictionary `shop_sum` using the code snippet below. The `if` statement checks if the `shop_id` has already exist in the dictionary `shop_sum` and initialises it to zero. The logic after the `if` performs the actual sum. You can write this code more elegantly using list comprehension, you may want to read up on [this](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html).

```
from collections import defaultdict

class OrderLine:
   def __init__(self, shop_id, qty, price):
    self.shop_id = shop_id
    self.qty = qty
    self.price = price

order_lines = [OrderLine(1, 2, 30), OrderLine(1, 1, 50), OrderLine(3, 3, 10)]
shop_sum = defaultdict(int)
for order_line in order_lines:
   shop_id =  order_line.shop_id  
   if shop_id not in shop_sum:
       shop_sum[shop_id]=0
   shop_sum[shop_id]  = shop_sum[shop_id] + order_line.qty * order_line.price
   print order_line.price
   print order_line.qty
   print order_line.shop_id
```

Comment: thanks, but this doesnt calculate the prices (I updated my question) please check it